# MySQL Php wont display data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been at this for several hours now and I have tried many different techniques but my if statement is not working, i only receive the echo "No Results", is there any simple reason that you can see as to why the data is not being displayed.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("gradumate_db")or die ("could not connect to db");

$groupName=$_POST['groupName'];
$timet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timetableA" ) or die ('Query is invalid');      

$run =mysql_query($timet);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

        $day = $rows['day'];
        $time = $rows['time'];
        $group = $rows['group'];
        $location = $rows['location'];

        echo "<p> Day: $day <br> Time: $time <br> Group: $group <br> Location: $location";
        exit();


    }
    else {
        echo "No Results";
    }

 ?>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: php doesn't "know" what $rows is, its currently undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$groupName=$_POST['groupName'];
$timet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users" ) or die ('Query is invalid');      

$run =$timet;
```

Explanation : at first you were using $timer inside mysql_query 2nd time,Compare my code with yours

And use while after if() to fetch more than 1 rows.

like

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

    $day = $rows['day'];
    $time = $rows['time'];
    $group = $rows['group'];
    $location = $rows['location'];
   //Your further code goes here
 }
```

Comment: My god, that was driving me crazy and such a simple problem solved, thanks a million I really appreciate it

Comment: @AlanMc , no issues ! **`:)`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract your data before you can call it. That's what functions like [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) are for. And you'll note that these functions are deprecated (see red box on the linked page).

You don't need `$run` since `$timet` has already executed the query.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($timet)>0){
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($timet);
```

Comment: @BigScar He has an `exit;` at the end or I would have

Answer (score 0):

> $timet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timetableA" ) or die ('Query is
>   invalid');
>   $run =mysql_query($timet);

this is wrong.
$run is not necessary, cuz you already made the query.

here is the corrected codes:

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("gradumate_db")or die ("could not connect to db");

$groupName=$_POST['groupName'];
$timet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timetableA" ) or die ('Query is invalid');      

if(mysql_num_rows($timet)>0){

    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($timet);

    $day = $rows['day'];
    $time = $rows['time'];
    $group = $rows['group'];
    $location = $rows['location'];

    echo "<p> Day: $day <br> Time: $time <br> Group: $group <br> Location: $location";
}
else {
    echo "No Results";
}
```

?>